# Fatal error: Call to undefined method stdClass::AddFile() in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 8

Tags: php

can someone please help, im getting this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method stdClass::AddFile() in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 8
```

***UPDATE
This is NEW my index.php:

```
<?php
define('IN_INDEX', 1);
include ('inc.php');
$TPL = new CoreScript_TPL();
$TPL->TPLDir = 'themes/'.$hotel[temp].'';
if(!isset($_GET['page']) || $_GET['page'] == 'index') {

    $TPL->AddFile('index');


}

echo $TPL->Run();

?>
```

The inc.php contains some includes, to the config, a class.template.php and my core.tpl.php, witch is this:

```
<?php

class CoreScript_TPL {

    public $TPLData;
    public $TPLDir;
    public $TPLVars = array();

    function AddFile($FileName) {
        if(file_exists($this->TPLDir . '/' . $FileName . '.tpl')) {
            $this->TPLData .= file_get_contents($this->TPLDir . '/' . $FileName . '.tpl');
            return true;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }

    function AssignVar($Variable, $Value) {
        $this->TPLVars[$Variable] = $Value;
    }

    function Run() {
        $OutputData = $this->TPLData;
        foreach($this->TPLVars as $key => $value) {
            $OutputData = str_replace('{'.$key . '}', $value, $OutputData);
        }
        return $OutputData;
    }

}
 ?>
```

What is needs to  do is request the theme name from the config.php and show that theme..
But it doesn't...
Can someone please help??

By the way, sorry for my bad english, i'm dutch....

Thanks,

Wesley Peeters

**UPDATE:

my class.template.php

```
if (!empty($TPL)) {
//Dingen die met het hotel te maken hebben
$TPL->setParameter('longname', $_CONFIG['hotel']['longname']);
$TPL->setParameter('shortname', $_CONFIG['hotel']['shortname']);
$TPL->setParameter('theme', $_CONFIG['hotel']['template']);
$TPL->setParameter('ip', $_CONFIG['hotel']['ip']);
$TPL->setParameter('build', $_CONFIG['hotel']['webbuild']);
$TPL->TPLDir = 'themes/'.$theme.'';
//Dingen die met SWF's te maken hebben
$TPL->setParameter('ext_vars', $_CONFIG['swf']['externalvars']);
$TPL->setParameter('productdata', $_CONFIG['swf']['productdata']);
$TPL->setParameter('furnidata', $_CONFIG['swf']['furnidata']);
$TPL->setParameter('external_texts', $_CONFIG['swf']['externaltexts']);
$TPL->setParameter('swfpath', $_CONFIG['swf']['path']);
//Overige
$TPL->setParameter('twitteruser', $_CONFIG['social']['twitter']);
$TPL->setParameter('fbuser', $_CONFIG['social']['facebook']);



}
```

Comment: You don't show anything creating `$TPL` - does it exist before you try and set a property on it? If not that's the cause.

Comment: Wait, i think u mean this, i'll update the post...

Comment: The updated code still shows no call to `$TPL = new CoreScript_TPL()` If you turn on E_STRICT, you ought to be seeing all sorts of warnings about creating a default object from an empty value.

Comment: I put the $TPL = new CoreScript_TPL(); in, now i gust have a whitescreen

Comment: You _must_ turn on error reporting in development. A white screen means a fatal error.  `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Error reporting was already on, still white screen

Comment: +1 Re-open vote, I don't see this question as a duplicate. Perhaps affecting a small amount of people, but as you can see. It's a call to an exisiting object which has been initialized with the method in place

Comment: I dont see why it should be reopened. The cause is obviously that $TPL is not a CoreScript_TPL object but instead gets initialized as a StdClass in the line after the call to the ctor when assigning the property to it. So the OP needs to find out why the call to `new` doesnt work

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the line to create `$TPL` as an instance of CoreScript_TPL:

```
$TPL = new CoreScript_TPL();
```

Without that, when you do `$TPL->TPLDir = ...`, PHP will create `$TPL` as a new, empty "stdClass" object, which won't have an `AddFile` method.

Comment: I don't really get what u mean, where do i put the line? because when i put it into the index.php it just shows me a white screen.....

Comment: @user2928643 You need to do it before you first start using the object. In your case I think that means do it in `class.template.php` after `if(!empty($TPL))`. Make sure you include `core.tpl.php` before `class.template.php`. Although, your class doesn't seem to have a setParameter method..(?)

Comment: @user2928643 Maybe that means it's working.

Comment: @user2928643 there's nothing in the question that adds any output so whitescreen doesn't mean anything specific.